# GitHub Mac app keeps adding SSH keys?

Tags: macos, git, ssh, github

My GitHub app seems to be adding new SSH keys to github every time I boot up my machine and startup GitHub app. This seems to me like that is not the way it was designed. Is there anyone with the same problem? Could it maybe be because of our changing IP address? (we've got to combined internet connections at the office)

Thanks!

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question as off-topic: please read the FAQ. It specifically lists questions about “tools commonly used by programmers” as welcomed.

Comment: Have you emailed support@github.com (as per http://mac.github.com/help.html)? What did they tell you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to be an issue with the Mac client. It was fixed in version 1.2.5 (Apr 12th 2012).

You can read the [release notes](http://mac.github.com/release-notes.html) for the client to see all the specifics.